# Rotate shapes to follow cursor in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've got the majority of this working. However the problem is occurring somewhere in my math calculations. I want the Arrows(user controls) to rotate to point towards the cursor as it's dragging around the canvas 'on click' in wpf. 
I've figured out how to calculate the angle in radians. However when i apply the value it doesn't appear to work as expected.

**Current**

[image]

**Goal**

[image]
[image]

The main snippet of code in focus is this...

```
private double Angle(Point origin, Point target)
        {
            //Calculate the distance from the square to the mouse's X and Y position
            var radians = Math.Atan2(origin.Y - target.Y, origin.X - target.X);
            var degrees = radians * (180 / Math.PI) - 90;

            Console.WriteLine(target + "--" + origin + "--" + degrees);
            return degrees;
        }

        private void Canvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {                                     
            var canvas = (Canvas)sender;

            if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                if (_followMouse)
                {
                    // Get Cursor Position
                    Point _targetPoint = e.GetPosition(this);

                    // Follow mouse
                    foreach (UIElement element in canvas.Children)
                    {                        
                        Arrow arrow = (Arrow)element;

                        // example 1
                        double x = Canvas.GetTop(arrow) + arrow.ActualWidth / 2.0;
                        double y = Canvas.GetLeft(arrow) + arrow.ActualHeight / 2.0;
                        Point _originPoint = new Point(x,y);

                        arrow.rotateTransform.Angle = Angle(_originPoint, _targetPoint);         
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

---

Entire project code below...

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        bool _followMouse;

        private void Canvas_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            _followMouse = true;
        }
        private void Canvas_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            _followMouse = false;
        }

        private double Angle(Point origin, Point target)
        {
            //Calculate the distance from the square to the mouse's X and Y position
            var radians = Math.Atan2(origin.Y - target.Y, origin.X - target.X);
            var degrees = radians * (180 / Math.PI) - 90;

            Console.WriteLine(target + "--" + origin + "--" + degrees);
            return degrees;
        }

        private void Canvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {                                     
            var canvas = (Canvas)sender;

            if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                if (_followMouse)
                {
                    // Get Cursor Position
                    Point _targetPoint = e.GetPosition(this);

                    // Follow mouse
                    foreach (UIElement element in canvas.Children)
                    {                        
                        Arrow arrow = (Arrow)element;

                        // example 1
                        double x = Canvas.GetTop(arrow) + arrow.ActualWidth / 2.0;
                        double y = Canvas.GetLeft(arrow) + arrow.ActualHeight / 2.0;
                        Point _originPoint = new Point(x,y);

                        arrow.rotateTransform.Angle = Angle(_originPoint, _targetPoint);         
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="300"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

    <Canvas
        MouseDown="Canvas_MouseDown" 
        MouseUp="Canvas_MouseUp"
        MouseMove="Canvas_MouseMove"
        Background="LightBlue">
        <local:Arrow Canvas.Left="158" Canvas.Top="43"/>
        <local:Arrow Canvas.Left="38" Canvas.Top="108"/>
        <local:Arrow Canvas.Left="158" Canvas.Top="170"/>
        <local:Arrow Canvas.Left="78" Canvas.Top="158"/>
        <local:Arrow Canvas.Left="196" Canvas.Top="108"/>
        <local:Arrow Canvas.Left="78" Canvas.Top="53"/>
    </Canvas>

</Window>
```

**Arrow.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.Arrow"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="50" d:DesignWidth="50">
    <Grid>
        <Path Data="M 0 4 L 4 0 L 8 4 Z" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
              Width="50"
              Height="50"
              Stretch="Uniform"
              Fill="Red">
            <Path.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform x:Name="rotateTransform"/>
            </Path.RenderTransform>

        </Path>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Are you sure the transformation needs to be in radians and not degrees?

Comment: I tried degrees and that didn't fix the issue either

Comment: That's what the two images under 'Goal' represent. I want the arrows to rotate to point towards the cursor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem essentially boils down to finding the angle between two vectors, the Vector at 0 angle (which is (0, -1)) and the vector from your arrow to the click point.

The math is fairly straight forward, acos(DotProduct(v1, v2)), as this is a very key equation there are many resources on why (http://www.wikihow.com/Find-the-Angle-Between-Two-Vectors).  Note though that this gives an unsigned angle between the vectors.  To figure out the sign, you should set your sign equivalent to the sign of the DotProduct of the vectorTo and an vector orthonormal to your 0-vector.

To put it in plain(er) terms, imagine the rotation being applied to the arms of a clock, where 0 angle is 12 (and is represented by the vector (0, -1)).  If you rotate by a positive angle, your result will have positive X values, as the tip of the arm will be to the right of the clock center (3 o-clock would be (0, 1)).  Rotating to the left will give you negative values (9 o-clock would be (0, -1).  Therefore, if you know your desired result ends up on the right (because your X value is positive), then you know the angle you rotate around should be positive, and vice versa.  That's essentially a simplified visual representation of the math above.

Anywho - the code.

```
private double Angle(Point origin, Point target)
{

    // Get the vector from origin->point
    Vector vecTo = target - origin;

    // Normalize the vector
    vecTo.Normalize();

    // 0-angle is pointing straight up, aligned with (0, -1). 
    // The equation for the angle between 2 vectors is acos(Dot(v1, v1))
    // Our DotProduct is trivial, as know v1 is (0, -1).  This exands
    // 0 * v2.X + -1 * v2.Y
    double dotAngle = -vecTo.Y;
    double angle = Math.Acos(dotAngle);

    // Convert to rad
    angle = angle * 180 / Math.PI;
    // ACos will always return a positive number, but because Cos is
    // symmetric around 0 a -ve number is also valid,  Figure out which
    // is correct by taking the Dot vs (1, 0).  If result is positive,
    // then vecTo point in the same general direction as (1, 0), and
    // the angle returned should also be positive.  I've skipped
    // all the actual math, but thats the idea.
    if (vecTo.X > 0)
        return angle;
    else
        return -angle;
}
```

Another problem though is that your X & Y coordinates are reversed for the arrows, it should be:

```
double y = Canvas.GetTop(arrow) + arrow.ActualWidth / 2.0;
double x = Canvas.GetLeft(arrow) + arrow.ActualHeight / 2.0;
Point _originPoint = new Point(x,y);
```

Whenever moving to a new graphics package, it always pays to work out which direction is up & right.  If you can't find documentation, just put a breakpoint in somewhere and click at the top-left and bottom-right and see what coordinates are spat out.

Comment: You mention in your comments...Figure out which
    // is correct by taking the Dot .... however the code you have supplied works as expected. Am I missing something?

Comment: You made it seem like i should be doing additional calculations.

Comment: The code I posted actually does do the dot product - The dot product of (X, Y) by (1, 0) is just 1 * X + 0 * Y == X.  I probably should have been more explicit, but I like the visual explanation, I find it easier to understand the clock than the abstract math

Comment: Alright, that makes sense then. Thank you for doing that i appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

In: var angleInRadians = Math.Atan2(yDiff, xDiff) * 180.0 / Math.PI;

Math.Atan2 already returns the vector in radians so the part "* 180.0 / Math.PI" is not necessary. In case you do need degrees rename the variable to angle instead of angleInRadian.

Comment: But the angle should be in **degrees** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.rotatetransform(v=vs.110).aspx so the calculation is necessary and correct.

Comment: Why does the rotation still appear incorrect though?

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer *why* this works, but I started from the assumption that getting the top and left isn't correct: you want to get the top center (the point of the arrow). Also, x should be the left, and y should be the top. Then add half the width to make x the center instead of the top left corner.

```
double x = Canvas.GetLeft(arrow);
double y = Canvas.GetTop(arrow);
x += (.5*arrow.ActualWidth);
```

That gets us close... The next part is the one I'm not sure about why it works, but it seems to work. Maybe someone better versed in math can help. Add 90 degrees to your angle:

```
arrow.rotateTransform.Angle = (angleInRadians+90);
```

I stumbled on this because it seems like the angle you're calculating isn't correct... By analyzing the values for top and left of the first arrow iterated over, I concluded it was the top most. Assuming that, clicking in the top left region should rotate it somewhere around 270 degrees, but I was getting values more near 180. So, I added 90, and it seems to work for any cursor position, although like I said I'm not sure why.

Comment: i only get one arrow to work, and that's only if the arrow is in the top left corner.